# not working login with linked in angular 7

Tags: angular7, linkedin-api

I have used angularx-social-login module for linkedin login.
But It not works.
I appreciate if you let me know the solution. thanks.

**UPDATE**
The library works fine with google but not with linkedin only.

I get this error when I call the linkedin login method.

[image]

Comment: what method should I use for it?